# EditText setError issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have set error message by **txt1.setError()** but it's not working all time I mean 
some time Error message is not completely showing . See both images.Give me suggestion.
`txt1.setError(getString(R.string.error_card));`

[image: working url]

Not working

[image]

Comment: You mean sometimes you did not get error on EditText ? Show me the xml.

Comment: please tell me your API level.

Comment: @praveenSharma API 16